# How to convert images in order

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a script that I want to converts images to animated gifs. Alas, they are not in the proper order! Ascending as 10,11,12...19,1,20,21...
where I really need it in 1,2,3,4....

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 0 22`
do
 convert -size 99x99 xc:red -font Palatino-Bold -pointsize 66 \
         -fill black -draw "text 20,55 '$i'" $i.png  
done
convert -delay 50 -loop  *.png output.gif
```

[image]

What should I do to get the gif animated in the correct order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name them properly in the first place.

```
"$(printf "%02d" "$i").png"
```

Comment: This works great, provided the number of pngs is 99 or less. Part of the problem is i have no idea about number of frames a user may choose to make.  if there are 100+ pngs, then this method will also screw up.

Comment: So then make the number of spaces as large as you may need, e.g. `%08d`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

Sort the files numerically before passing them to convert.

```
convert -delay 50 -loop  $(ls *.png | sort -n) output.gif
```

Comment: when i run this line, imagemagick throws some sort of error::
"IHDRc��N��PLTE���s���8���` @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1901."